# Mailbox can't synchronize appointment, contact, and tasks

Tags: office-365, crm

I've got a mailbox in Dynamics CRM which is throwing the error "Mailbox can't synchronize appointments, contact, and tasks. Another Microsoft Dynamics CRM organization is configured to the same Exchange email address specified in this mailbox."

But there isn't another CRM organization!  Any ideas as to what's causing it and how to resolve?

The only thing I can think of is that we upgraded the O365 account to an E3 license.  Could that cause it thinking it was linked to another organisation?